# React-Native/Firestore - Search by date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a search filter where you can filter by specific date. Not sure what the problem is. It's a react-native project where i'm using hooks (useEffect) to read firestore data. That part work wery well. However i want to  apply a searchfilter where you can select both location and date.

The location part works like a charm. Here is some code example:

```
   useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("Name of the collection")
      .where("location", "==", props.searchLocation) 
      .where("date", "==", props.searchDate)
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
```

If i delete the date query part then the location part works fine. Also if i change == to >= on the date part then it displays the data from the selected date and forward.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("Name of collection")
      .where("location", "==", props.searchLocation)
      .where("date", "=<", props.searchDate)
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
```

But the thing is that i want it to only display the data from the selected date. If i console.log the props.SearchDate then the format looks like this: 
2019-11-09T00:00:00.000Z.

I'm using react-native base DatePicker to be able to choose date and i also got Moment.js to display the date.

Any thoughts on this? Does it have  anything to do with the date format and time format?

> **Update 1**

The code im using to set the props.Searchdate and a screenshot of console.log() + instanceof Date

```
Screen.js  
const [searchDate, setSearchDate] = useState(new Date());
console.log(searchDate instanceof Date);
console.log(searchDate);

component.js
  const datePicker = value => {
    new Date(props.setSearchDate(value));
  };
```

[expo console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFoBB.jpg)

> **Update 2 - My solution**

I did solve it with creating two conts at the beginning of the useEffect where i set the time of the chosen date.

Then i query the data by two .where() arguments.

This is my solution if anyone else strugeling with the same thing. However i dont know if it is the best practice.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const date1 = new Date(props.searchDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
    const date2 = new Date(props.searchDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 59));
    console.log(date1);
    console.log(date2);
    db.collection("Name of collection")
      .where("location", "==", props.searchLocation)
      .where("date", ">=", date1)
      .where("date", "<=", date2)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `props.searchDate` is an object of type Date or Timestamp?

Comment: Updated the original post now